# How to test my ios app in ios 4.3 version?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, xcode4.3

i am running with the latest IOS Xcode and itunes versions now.
i have released one of my apps one week ago and 4.3 users have a crash a a specific point.
there is no option to test my app on the simulator, its gotta run on a real device, any ideas how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.redmondpie.com/downgrade-5.1-to-5.0.1-5.0-4.3.3-4.3.5-on-iphone-ipad-ipod-touch-how-to-tutorial/

That link can show you how to downgrade

Otherwise the simulator should be a good place to test unless your game has a "power" attribute, like a game, in that case the simulator (which is essentially the iMac) will perform better and different than a device. Otherwise you can go into the project/target settings and change the build version type to a lower version